# Calling a javascript function in html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on javascript and html. I have a javascript function, called login, and I want to call this function in HTML. I saw some codes that includes the javascript function directly in the HTML. I don't want to do it because the code is very long.
Here is the HTML:

```
<input class="form-control form-stacked" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" required="true" id="username">
<input class="form-control form-stacked last" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" required="true" id="password">
<script>
    window.onload = login()
</script>
<input class="btn btn-beats btn-block btn-stacked" value="Tune in" type="submit">
```

And the Javascript function is:

```
function login(){

    var userName = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    console.log(userName);
    console.log(password);
    var data = {
        userName : userName,
        password : password
    };
    console.log(data);
    doJSONRequest("POST", "/login", {}, data, function(location){
        document.location = location.location;
    });
    }
```

I included a window.onload because I want to call the function when the page started. The console (obliviously) says to me that "login in not defined" and, of course, it has reason. But I don't want to put all the code into the HTML (also because there are like 30 lines more). Can you help me please? Thanks to everyone :)

Comment: Are you seeking for the [`src` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-src) of the `script` tag?

Comment: don't you want to call login after the user has entered a username and password?

Comment: Also, `window.onload = login()` should be `window.onload = login`. You don't want to call the function, you want to assign it to `onload` so that the browser can call it.

Comment: Yes @Cfreak I want to call it when the user put username and password to check if they exist in a database

Comment: ok. That's a good point @FelixKling Thanks

Comment: It seems like you are actually asking how to execute a function upon user interaction, such as filling in the input or submitting the form. Have a look at the change, click and submit events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit

Comment: Your login function needs to be defined in a src file. Once its there it will be loaded and you can call it. There's not really a reason to add it to the `onload()` method. You do, however need to call it on the submit of you form.

Comment: So, let see if I understand... I have to do a src tag?

Comment: I know it does not work because I put a console log and in the console I don't have anything

Comment: Thanks to everybody but I solve it alone

Comment: I think better if you add the solution as a new answer (by clicking add answer at the bottom of the page) without editing the question.. (It's the way used in this site)

Comment: aaah ok. I will do it

Answer (score 0):

Put the javascript in another js file(eg: filename.js) and load it load it in the header..

```
<script src="path to the file"></script>
```

Also you have to change `window.onload = login()` to `window.onload = login`

`window.onload` expects a reference of a function. When you use `window.onload = login()` the return value of the `login()` function is set as the reference which is not correct. The function name `login` is the reference..

Comment: <script src="js/data.js"></script> I thought was to long to put all the HTML page

Comment: Did you put that <script src="js/data.js"></script> inside the <head></head> tags?

Comment: Your path is correct? Are you sure the js file is loaded?

Comment: Because I have another function in there and it works

Comment: I know it does not work because I put a console log and in the console I don't have anything

Comment: If you are using chrome, press F11 and select network tab. Reload the page. Then the file "data.js" will be listed there. Check if it contains the latest code.. I mean to check if this is a caching issue..

Comment: with F12 I go to the first page on my laptop (I'm working with 5 different)

Comment: What was the problem? Just curious to know.. :)

Comment: Of course man. Look at my edit. I will introduce my solution also for other people

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is to run your login code when the user clicks on the button. You can do that this way:

```
<form>
    <input class="form-control form-stacked" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" required="true" id="username">
    <input class="form-control form-stacked last" name="password" placeholder="Password" type="password" required="true" id="password">
    <input class="btn btn-beats btn-block btn-stacked" value="Tune in" onclick="login()">
</form>
<script src="login.js></script>
```

login.js:

```
   function login(){

      var userName = document.getElementById("username").value;
      var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
      console.log(userName);
      console.log(password);
      var data = {
                userName : userName,
                password : password
      };
      console.log(data);
      doJSONRequest("POST", "/login", {}, data, function(location){
          ...
      });
```

Comment: Yes M.Page but as I already said "I don't want to add the entire function (That are more than 100 lines) into the HTML file. I asked if there is a method to call this function in the HTML because i know how to do it with functions in HTML

Comment: Updated my edit. I thought you  meant "not inside the code of the button". Sorry.

Comment: I saw it I'm trying your solution

Comment: loading it through a javascript file is the standard and efficient way of loading javascript code.

Comment: It still does not work because I put a console.log but I don't see it

Comment: Do you mean `console.log(userName);` doesn't display anything ? If so, be sure 1. you used the `onclick` attribute in the HTML code. 2. Trim down `login` function to `function login(){console.log('ok');}` to be sure sure that your JS script file is correctly linked to your HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION

Just to be correct with the other users here is my solution:

```
 <form action="login.html" method="POST" class="form-signup">
    <input class="form-control form-stacked" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" type="text" required="true">
    <input class="form-control form-stacked" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" type="text" required="true">
    <input class="form-control form-stacked" name="username" placeholder="Username" type="text" required="true" id="username" onkeyup="login()">
    <input class="form-control form-stacked" name="email" placeholder="email" type="email" required="true">
    <input class="form-control form-stacked" name="password" id = "password" placeholder="Password" type="password" required="true" onkeyup="login()">
    <input class="form-control form-stacked last" name="repeatPassword" id="repeat" placeholder="Repeat password" type="password" onkeyup="enable()" required="true">
    <input class="btn btn-beats btn-block btn-stacked" value="Sign up" id = "btnPlaceOrder" type="submit">
  </form>
```

I just add the function "login" when the user wants to store the values